# Calculate intersection of labels in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to construct a matrix made up of indicator values, taking the value 1 if the labels have elements in common.
Ultimately, I want to create a database that reports whether two elements match

```
N <- 100
combinations <- c(outer(letters[1:5], letters[1:5], paste0))

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  c_1 = sample(x=combinations,size = N,replace = T),
  c_2 = sample(x=c(rep(NA,N/4),combinations),size = N,replace = T),
  c_3 = sample(x=c(rep(NA,N/2),combinations),size = N,replace = T),
  c_4 = sample(x=c(rep(NA,N/1),combinations),size = N,replace = T)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(c_all=list(c(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)[!is.na(c(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4))]))

match_function <- function(x,y){
  result <- ifelse(length(intersect(x,y)),1,0)
  return(result)
}

outer(data$c_all, unlist(data$c_all)), match_function)
```

Comment: what are `pseudo_lastnames`

Comment: Just a typo in the preparation of the toy model!

Comment: The following line does not run : `outer(data$c_all, unlist(data$c_all)), match_function)`, problem of parenthesis surely